# Difference between CMD echo 'Hello world' and CMD ["echo", ''Hello world'] in a dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Just I would like to know if there is some difference behind the scenes between doing:

```
CMD echo 'Hello world'
```

and

```
CMD ['echo', 'Hello World']
```

I know that both will print it on the console , but if there is some difference, when use each option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is not much difference in your simple example, but there will be a difference if you need shell features such as variable substitution e.g. `$HOME`.

This is the shell form.  It will invoke a command shell:

```
CMD echo 'Hello world'
```

This is the exec form.  It does not invoke a command shell:

```
CMD ["/usr/bin/echo", "Hello World"]
```

The exec form is parsed as a JSON array, which means that you should be using double-quotes around words, not single-quotes, and you should give the full path to an executable. The exec form is the preferred format of CMD.

Comment: Thanks wim. So it is called exec form. It is the same of docker run exec --it ...?

Comment: It has no relation to `docker exec`.  The plain-command form is identical to `docker run sh -c "echo 'Hello World'"`.